# Can you get 18V from two 9V batteries

Tags: voltage, batteries

Can I get 18V from two 9V batteries if I join two together?

How will I join them?

Comment: In series, positive to negative.

Comment: 9V batteries have quite a unique feature in that they can be clipped together without needing any extra hardware, the longest 'stack' I've seen developed some 200V or so.

Comment: @Sam - Here's a [video of some crazy dude who clipped 244 of them and got about 2000V out if it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hwLHdBTQ7s).

Comment: @Ricardo Ah that's the one, I knew there was 200-somethings involved, I just couldn't remember if it was batteries or volts

Comment: Look inside the battery door of your TV remote.  What do you see?  Why do you think they did it that way?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, two 9 V batteries in series results in one 18 V battery.  You connect the + end of one battery to the - end of the other.  The remaining unconnected battery ends are the ends of the overall 18 V battery.

While you get more voltage, you don't get more current.  If each battery is capable of 9 V at 300 mA, for example, then the combined battery is capable of 18 V at 300 mA.

Comment: Also, make sure they are both new batteries of the same brand and type.

Comment: After using them for a time they wont any longer be new. Should you stop using them in this fashion then? Also I don't see why they must be of the same brand if they are the same type and you trust both brands specifications.

Comment: @Jose: What he really meant is that any set of batteries you string together should be matched.  For normal consumer batteries, the best way to make that likely is for all the batteries to be of the same model and all fresh.  With unmatched batteries, some will deplete before others, making the whole string seem worse than most of the batteries actually are.  Worst case a bad battery gets reverse biased, which could cause it to leak or even explode.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Off-topic: Heading to your site `http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm`, Chrome gives a warning: "The site ahead contains harmful programs" https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?hl=en

Comment: On the other hand, consumers have been happily sticking multiple cells of whatever type they found in the kitchen drawer together into battery boxes for decades, without significant harm or explosions.

Comment: if you take apart the 9V itself, you'll see that internally it is doing the same thing.  It isn't a single large, 9v battery, but a series of either 1.5V or 3V.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, I'm well aware of that.  Google's virus checkers get a false positive on some of our executables.  Apparently something in one of our libraries has a matching byte sequence somewhere.  Unfortunately, trying to explain this to Google is futile. *"We don't care, we don't have to.  We're Google."*  Better browsers don't seem to have this problem.

Comment: @Ian: First 9 V batteries are rarely strung together.  Second, people that did this probably did get less battery life out of the fresher cells than they should have.  Third, every once in a while you do get leaking batteries, which then often ruin whatever equipment they are in, or at least corrode the battery contacts.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, they can be connected in series. You can snap them together (female to male snap) and they will be connected correctly. The voltage is doubled and the Ah life is the same (but twice the voltage, so twice the energy, as you might expect). Or just connect the wires from the snaps as shown below (image from [here](https://www.ultimate-guitar.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1254306)).

[image]

If you choose to clip more than a few together you should take appropriate safety precautions. The 'crazy dude' in the comments who linked 244 together to get ~2kV has an [electric chair supply](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/10/20/the_odd_body_electrocution/) on his hands. The short-circuit current of a fresh alkaline 9V battery is about 3A, meaning that string could supply >1kV at 1.5A.

Even if the current didn't go through your heart, the resulting 1.5kW of heat would quickly cause severe tissue damage. Allegedly DC can be more dangerous than AC because it makes it harder to let go. I don't know that there have ever been detailed experiments done on this (perhaps some organization such as Unit 731 did). In any case, avoid getting shocked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, battery ones negative pin goes to battery twos positive pin. Then the positive of battery one is your 18 volts, negative of battery two is your ground.